# What's the best way to discretize a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, binning

I am working on a two-dimensional grid representing some physical properties at given spatial intervals.

Let's say that I know there is a Gaussian distribution for $P(X=x \mid A=a)$, the probability of landing a dart at $x$ given that I am actually aiming at $a$. I happen to know there is no covariance between the horizontal and vertical components of $X$.

Since I'm dealing with discrete data points, I need to come up with a way to describe the probability of landing at those points. So I need a way to descretize my distribution. I researched one method and thought of another:

1. Scale space representation of a Gaussian kernel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_space_implementation#The_discrete_Gaussian_kernel
2. And my other thought was to repeatedly integrate my pdf at each point over some area around the point. Something like

$$\int_{x - \frac{\Delta}{2}}^{x + \frac{\Delta}{2}} f_{X}dx$$

Where $\Delta$ is just the space between discrete points on the grid.

**#2** seems somewhat tedious if my grid is large, plus I'd need to work out how to account for the edges and corners of my grid. As for **#1**, I'm having a hard time digesting the Wikipedia article. Specifically, I'm not sure if it is okay to remove that method from the context of image smoothing and use it for my seemingly different purpose.

Expanding on the question in the title, **Are both of these methods equally valid and/or do they have drawbacks?**

Comment: (2) is fully correct.  (1) is an approximation that usually is excellent.  It is surprisingly fast and easy to do (2) on some platforms, such as `R`.